# How to get "authorization code" in Spotify iOS SDK

Tags: python, ios, spotify

I am building an iOS app that integrates with Spotify. I would like my app users to authorize my app to use their Spotify account( read library/modify playlists.etc). My app's logic is mainly server-side. I am able to get an access token using the latest release of Spotify SDK, but I'm not getting any refresh token or authorization code. With Facebook and other services, I am sending the access token that I'm getting on the iOS to my backend and then I'm storing it and refreshing it with server-to-server requests. It seems the the provided token service still still requires an "authorization code" from ios client to be sent to this service. I am not getting such code nor am I getting a refresh token.

TL;DR: What's the best way to handle Spotify Web API access token refresh for a server-backed iOS app ? What is needed to be done on iOS to be able to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is to follow Spotify workflow (https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#authorization_code_flow). This process will require a token refresh service running on a public site. I used the python/cherrypie script (https://github.com/plamere/spotify_token_swap). The only caveat is that you need to change

1. The app client_id/secret/callback to match your app
2. Spotify Account Services endpoint ( change it FROM https://ws.spotify.com/oauth/token  TO https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token)

Then run the script on a PUBLIC site and provide the URL to the ios app as swapServiceURL = "http://example.com/swap"

Comment: Can you explain this in more detail? Why do I need a website to use Spotify on iOS? Would be great if we could chat on here or on twitter.